# tire leaks with chrome wheels

Tags: wheels

I had a flat repaired recently and was told it was the result of having chrome wheels.  Something about rust building up in the wheel where it meets the tire and causing a gap, thus the air leak.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is your actual question here?

Comment: Presumably the wheels are chrome plated steel . Chrome gives good corrosion protection but there are always imperfections : No doubt , porous  rust build-up at an imperfections in the chrome caused the leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a rim that is rusting between the tire and rim. This is common throughout all rims.  When new tires are placed on the rims the installer must clean the rim by grinding with an abrasive media. Once clean they should apply a sealant to the rim and tire where they meet. This should last the life of the tire. If this happens before the tires are replaced the same thing can be done.
This will happen a lot faster with aluminum rims and would cost the same labor as installing new tires. Tires should be balanced after removing them from the rim.

Answer (score 0):

a reputable tire shop would grind the rim edge for you.  This isn't a problem specific to chrome wheels.  Most factory wheels on older cars are iron.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any excess air left in the tire by putting pressure on the valve stem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  How does this answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Having a chrome wheel isn't causing the tire flat, that was absurd and lazy reason because the chrome is actually eliminating the rust problem.

What was causing is could be several causes, such as:

- Improper installation
- Dented rims
- Defected rims
- Leaking tire nozzle
- Defected Tire

The reason having rust inside the rims usually because water content in your tire's air that's why there is nitrogen for tire for zero water content*

But with the chrome plated rims it should be eliminated the problem, the reason usually improper installation like using improper tools when installing the tire and make the rims scratched on the tire lips this way could make a rust and eventually flatting your tire.

Using improper tools could make your rims to be dented on the lips. Because tubeless tire depends entirely on the rim lips it should be smooth and nice round without a dent.